# Issue in dynamically create multiple ui tinymce editor angularjs

Tags: angularjs, tinymce-4

I am creating multiple tinymce editor for each selected user.
editors were create correctly if number of users are less (below 10).
if users limit exceeds above 10, then editors will be applied to only few text areas and not applied for few text areas.

[Please refer this image for my issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wo6pa.png)

please refer the image above.
**My view is:**

```
<div ng-repeat="selnominee in pepsicoNomination.selectedNomineesforContribution track by $index">
<textarea class="contri_txtarea"
                                      ng-model="selnominee.NomineeDetails.Contribution" ui-tinymce="tinymceNominee.options" rows="13" cols="80" required></textarea>
</div>
```

Based on the length of "pepsicoNomination.selectedNomineesforContribution" , number of text areas will be created and editor need to applied to those text areas.

**My script is:**

```
$scope.tinymceNominee = {
            cmtsCharLength: 0,
            options: {
                height: 175,
                theme: 'modern',
                plugins: [
                    "advlist autolink lists link image  hr anchor charcount  autoresize"
                ],
                toolbar1: "bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link",
                menubar: false,
                browser_spellcheck: true,
                gecko_spellcheck: true,
                content_css: [
                    '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i',
                    '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
                ],
                resize: true,
                elementpath: false,
                autoresize_min_height: 175,
                autoresize_max_height: 600,
                setup: function (ed) {

                   ed.on('resizeeditor', function (e) {
                        $('.mce-tinymce').width("100%");
                    });

                   ed.on('keydown', function (e) {
                        var allowedKeys = [8, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 45, 46];
                        if (allowedKeys.indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1) return true;

                       var txtLength = CountCharacters(ed.id);
                        if (txtLength >= $scope.pepsicoNomination.Band.ContributionCharCount) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            e.stopPropagation();
                            return false;
                        }
                        $scope.cmtsCharLength = txtLength;
                        return true;
                    });

                   ed.on('keyup', function (e) {
                        var count = CountCharacters(ed.id);
                        $scope.cmtsCharLength = count;
                    });
                },
                mode: 'exact'
            }
        };
```

Comment: I provided timeout to load that div.'<div ng-show="showContribution"><div ng-repeat="nominee in selectedNominees track by $index">
<textarea class="contri_txtarea"  ng-model="nominee.Contribution" ui-tinymce="tinymceNominee.options" required></textarea> </div></div>'I have show this div on certain condition in page load. on that place only number of users were decided. Under that condition, i tried with timeout like below:'$timeout(function () {$scope.showContribution = true;}, 500);'on create, all text editors displayed correctly. But on edit, same issue happened.

Answer (score 0):

There is  bug in some version of TinyMCE. The Ids generated by the directive sometimes have the same name. Open your ui-tinymce.js file and change the following line :

```
attrs.$set('id', ID_ATTR + '-' + (new Date().valueOf()));
```

to:

```
attrs.$set('id', ID_ATTR + '-' + (new Date().getTime().valueOf()));
```

This will make sure all Ids are unique.